# Java - creating an input limit for my constructor

Tags: java, constraints

I received an assignment for school where they ask me to build a simple clock with some functions.

I need some kind of constraint so that if i create an object people are only allowed to input good integers. For example; you are not allowed to enter 25 at hours or a integer higher then 60 at minutes and seconds.

I started creating instance variables for Hours, minutes and seconds. I created a constructor;

My code is below:

```
public class Clock{

    //Instance variables
    public int seconds;
    public int minutes;
    public int hours;

public Clock ( int InsertSeconds, int InsertMinutes, int InsertHours){
    seconds = InsertSeconds;
    minutes = InsertMinutes;
    hours   = InsertHours;
}

}
```

Ps; I am beginner at java, don't fire shots at me

Thanks!

Comment: If you are allowed to use Date and Time libraries - try using TimeValidator by Apache - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/TimeValidator.html

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is good habit to first show what you have tried. Please edit your question accordingly. Hint: you might want to check wether the values entered are valid and throw an exception if not.

Comment: Have a look at java basic operators ( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm), decision making (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_decision_making.htm) and exceptions (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) then come back with precise questions.

Comment: @hagubear I am allowed i guess. but  for a beginner it's not that smart to use existing classes at start. Thanks though

Comment: I am aware of the basic operators @MarkusWMahlberg, but somehow i am having really trouble to combine or putting things at the right place. My class is is going way to fast for me! I have some piece of code that works already but it's from the book, but i can't figure out what they are doing

Comment: @WinstonNolten: Have a look at Nikolar's answer. This will give you an idea. If done properly, this "pattern" will prevent the creation of illegal objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an exception. [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) would be a good choice.

```
public Clock ( int InsertSeconds, int InsertMinutes, int InsertHours){
    if (InsertSeconds > 59 || InsertSeconds < 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("InsertSeconds must be in range 0-59 but found "+ InsertSeconds);
    }
    // similar for minutes & hours

    seconds = InsertSeconds;
    minutes = InsertMinutes;
    hours   = InsertHours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions! For example:

```
if(seconds > 60)
     throw new SecondsTooBigException();
```

And you'll have to create a new SecondsTooBigExcetion

```
public class SecondsTooBigException extends Exception {
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return super.getMessage() + "\nSecondsTooBigException: Exception occured, because you defined a value, which is not allowed for seconds";
    }
}
```

Comment: If needed, you can override other methods, too.

Comment: Thanks all! Really need this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your clock has a 24 hour format (i.e. a simple solution), you can use a basic flow control:

```
public boolean areAllSegmentsValid() {
    if (this.hours < 0 || this.hours > 24) {
        System.out.println("Hours are not in range 0-24");
        // A better of option wil be exception (you are novice so learn about first)
        return false;
    } else if (this.minutes < 0 || this.minutes > 60){
        System.out.println("Minutes are not in range 0-24");
        // A better of option wil be exception (you are novice so learn about first)
    } else if (this.seconds < 0 || this.seconds > 60){
        System.out.println("Minutes are not in range 0-24");
        // A better of option wil be exception (you are novice so learn about first)
    } else {
        return true;
   }

   return true;
}
```

The above solution requires you to have the minimum understanding of Java, which you already have pointed out in your original question. Once you grasp this concept, I suggest you try and use assertions to replace the if conditions above e.g.:

```
assert (this.hours >= 0 && this.hours<=24); // Assertion to check if the cond. is true
...
...
```

The more Java way is to use exceptions for your Clock class e.g. IllegalHoursValue exception, or IllegalTimeSegment exception. However, I will leave you here to investigate the rest for your safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this static method:

```
public static boolean validTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    if (hours <= 24 && minutes <= 60 && seconds <= 60) {
        if (hours >= 0 && minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Give it the values that the user inputs. If it returns `true` then pass it to the constructor, otherwise ask the user to input the values again.

Comment: While i was continuing my assignment i found out that the  throw new IllegalArgumentException was useless because later on they ask me to implement another option.

If i increase the seconds or minutes with with a value so that the tot value will exceed with beyond 60 it has to increase the other with 1 i.e. If i hake the following time 10:12:59 seconds and i increase that time with 1 second the outcome has to be 10:13:00

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue, I would recommend that you ask a new question and see if someone is able to help you.